# Override the Content-Type when using FineUploader direct to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I want to override the Content-Type to "application/octet-stream" when sending any file to s3 with fine uploader.

I am uploading video files and when retrieving them I never want them to opened by the browser I always want the downloaded.

I tried overriding it in the signature signing but then the upload fails the signature test. Can I get fine uploader to tell s3 it to save it as a "application/octet-stream"?

Or is there a way when generating a pre-signed url with the AWS SDK to tell it to always send as "application/octet-stream"? I thought this might do that, but in chrome at least it tries to play a video in the browser.

```
var headerOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides { ContentType = "application/octet-stream" };

var urlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
        BucketName = _bucketName,
        Key = key,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
        ResponseHeaderOverrides = headerOverrides,
        Protocol = Protocol.HTTPS,
        Verb = HttpVerb.GET
 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `Content-Type` header to some generic value is not the proper way to solve your problem.  Instead, you'll need to set the appropriate `Content-Disposition` header.  Currently, you'll need to make this adjustment on your object via the sever using the S3 API [as part of handling Fine Uploader's upload success call](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html#optional-server-side-tasks-all-browsers).  There is [an open case to allow these types of headers to be associated with each object client-side](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/pull/1258).

Comment: Excellent, rather than changing the Content-Disposition on upload success I just altered it on when creating the PreSignedUrlRequest like this..`var headerOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides { ContentType = "application/octet-stream", ContentDisposition = string.Format("application/octet-stream; filename={0}", fileName) };`

Comment: @NoseBagUK I'm pretty sure you want to use "attachment" instead of "application/octet-stream".

Comment: When you say "you'll need to make this adjustment on your object via the sever," do you mean copying the object and supplementing the headers you want? I need to set `Cache-Control` on my objects somehow. Also, when do you expect 5.5.0 to be released?